# Excel: Fill D1 with 'Incomplete' if data is entered in A1 and either or both B1 and C2 are blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to do checks on a series of row and denote this.

How can I fill D1 with the phrase 'Incomplete' if data is entered in A1 and either or both B1 and C2 are blank?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the formula `=IF(A1="","",IF(OR(B1="",C1=""),"Incomplete",""))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in D1:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",OR(ISBLANK(B1),ISBLANK(C1))),"Incomplete","")
```